# Java GUI: Age Calculator: Trying to get my Output.Text.setText to output the Current Year - The Year Born

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm pretty new to learning Java and well I am writing a program that takes in your birthday, and subtracts the year by the current year.

I have my output set Text ready in order to set the text to the correct Textbox. My problem is I can't take the current year and subtract the year that was inputted by the user due to it being a String and not an integer. My code is below

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

public class AgeCalculator  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        JFrame appFrame = new JFrame("Age Calculator");

        appFrame.setSize(390, 300);
        appFrame.setLocation(100, 150);
        appFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Label and TextField
        JLabel Day = new JLabel("Day Born:");
        Day.setBounds(10, 10, 200, 30);
        JTextField DayText = new JTextField();
        DayText.setBounds(85, 10, 200, 30);



        //Month Label and TextField
        JLabel Month = new JLabel("Month Born:");
        Month.setBounds(10, 50, 200, 30);
        JTextField MonthText = new JTextField();
        MonthText.setBounds(85, 50, 200, 30);




        //Year Label and TextField
        JLabel Year = new JLabel("Year Born:");
        Year.setBounds(10, 90, 200, 30);
        JTextField YearText = new JTextField();
        YearText.setBounds(85, 90, 200, 30);


        //Output Field
        JLabel OutputLabel = new JLabel("Your Current Age Is:");
        OutputLabel.setBounds(10, 220, 200, 30);
        JTextField OutputText = new JTextField();
        OutputText.setBounds(125, 220, 235, 30);



        //Formatting the System's current time
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(("yyyy"));
        Date date = new Date();
        JLabel CurrentYear = new JLabel("Current Year: ");
        CurrentYear.setBounds(10, 135, 200, 30);



        //Printing that current time
        JTextField DateText = new JTextField(dateFormat.format(date));
        DateText.setBounds(87, 135, 200, 30);


        //Adding objects to our Frame
        appFrame.add(Day);
        appFrame.add(Month);
        appFrame.add(Year);
        appFrame.add(CurrentYear);
        appFrame.add(DayText);
        appFrame.add(YearText);
        appFrame.add(MonthText);
        appFrame.add(DateText);
        appFrame.add(OutputText);
        appFrame.add(OutputLabel);


        //Settings
        appFrame.setLayout(null);
        appFrame.setVisible(true);
        appFrame.setResizable(false);


        //Our Submit button
        JButton appButton = new JButton("Calculate Age");
        appButton.setBounds(120, 170, 120, 30);
        appFrame.add(appButton);

        appButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                String StrYearText = YearText.getText();
                int val = Integer.parseInt(CurrentYear.getText()) - Integer.parseInt(StrYearText);

            OutputText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
            
                //OutputText.setText(YearText.getText());

                //CURRENT YEAR - YEAR BORN! UGH


            }
        });

    }


}
```

Comment: You're already using `parseInt`. So what is the problem?

Comment: Look closely at your exception: You're trying to parse an `int` from your **Label** `CurrentYear`. Surely you meant to parse the `int` of your `TextField`, no?

Comment: This is an example of the importance of following Java naming conventions and naming your variables and controls something meaningful. :)

Comment: @Zephyr Hmm I will check real quick with parsing the TextField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few issues in your code. First of all, you are trying to parse an `int` from a `Label` (`CurrentYear`). Your exception would make it clear that you cannot get an `int` from the `String` "Current Year: ".

You are also not using the birth year that the user enters. Update your code as follows:

```
int currentYear = Integer.parseInt(DateText.getText());
int birthYear = Integer.parseInt(YearText.getText());

int val = currentYear - birthYear;

OutputText.setText(String.valueOf(val));
```

Though I also highly recommend learning the Java naming conventions and stick with them. Make sure you give your controls and variables meaningful names (ie: at a glance, do you know what `YearText` and `DateText` refer to?).

Comment: Thank you, this works correctly and I will definitely be looking into better naming conventions since I most definitely confused myself.

Answer (score 0):

Changes CurrentYear to DateText

```
int val = Integer.parseInt(DateText.getText()) - Integer.parseInt(StrYearText);
```